# C# Regex.Replace Multiple Newlines

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text file that contains more or less paragraphs.  The text is not actually words, its comma delimited data; but that's not really that important.  The text file is sort of divided into sections; there can be sections, and subsections.  The division of sections is denoted by more than one newlines and subsections by a newline.

So sample data:

```
This is the, start of a, section
908690,246246246,246246
246246,246,246246

This is, the next, section,
sfhklj,sfhjk,4626246
4yw2,fdhds5juj,53ujj
```

So the above data contains two sections, each with three subsections.  Sometimes however, there is more than one empty line between sections.  When this occurs, I want to convert the multiple newline characters, say `\n\n\n\n` to just `\n\n`; I think regex is probably the way to do this.  I also may need to use different newline standards, unix `\n`, and windows `\r\n`.  I think the files probably contain multiple endline encodings.

Here is the regex that I've come up with; its nothing special:

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"([\r\n|\n]{2,})", Enviroment.NewLine + Enviroment.NewLine}
```

Firstly, is this a good regex solution?  I'm not that good with regex.

Secondly,  I then want to split each section into an element in a string array:

```
Regex.Split(input, Enviroment.NewLine + Enviroment.NewLine)
```

Is there a way to combine these steps?

Comment: I guess you should first replace `([\r\n|\n])` with `Enviroment.NewLine` to keep the data consistent. And I don't know of a way to optimize it, I guess you can't combine them. I guess you are on the right way. You might want to set `RegexOptions.Compiled` to make it faster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[\r\n|\n]` is wrong.  That's a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that matches one of the characters `\r`, `\n`, or `|`.

Common idioms for matching a generic line separator are `(?:\r\n|[\r\n])` or `(?:\n|\r\n?)`.  These will match `\r\n` (DOS/Windows), `\r` (older Macintosh), or `\n` (Unix/Linux/Mac OS X).

I would normalize all line separators to `\n`, then split on two or more of those:

```
Regex.Split(Regex.Replace(source, @"(?:\r\n|[\r\n])", "\n"), @"\n{2,}")
```

Comment: Great, thanks.  Exactly what I was looking for.  Its good to know my regex was at least semi on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

I will just use `String.Split` and first split the text into sections using double newlines as delimiter, then split each of the section into subsection using single newline as delimiter.
You will then end up with the array you wanted. You can use `List<string>` object as the container and add the array returned from the split method using `AddRange` to the container.